# Slowing down PyGame sprite animation without lowering frame rate

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I am trying to learn pygame sprite animation. I have tried to follow a tutorial and everything is fine. There is just one problem that I can't get my head around.

In the below code I am trying to run a sprite animation of simples square.
This is the sprite:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xa39gb6m3k8085c/playersprites.png

I can get it working, but the animation is too fast. I want it to be little smoother so that the fading effect can be seen. I saw some solutions using `clock.tick` but that would slow down the whole game I guess.

***how can I get the animation slower while maintaing the usual frame rate for my window?***

Below is my code:

```
lightblue=(0,174,255)
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False
screen.fill(lightblue)
images=pygame.image.load('playersprites.png')
noi=16
current_image=0
while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
        if(current_image>noi-1):
            current_image=0
        else:
            current_image+=1
        screen.blit(images,(50,100),(current_image*32,0,32,32))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Use an integer value which you add to in the loop and check for divisibility.

Comment: See [here](http://repl.it/jRA) for what I mean.

Comment: @malik brahimi , can you please explain a little what you did

Comment: So there is a integer used to count starting at zero before the loop. Then we simply update the image at a fixed interval using modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an integer value which you add to in the loop and check for divisibility. See [here](http://repl.it/jRA) for more.

Answer (score 2):

You could use time

So your sprite has 16 frames and lets say it wants to run at ten frames a second regardless of the frame rate of the game.

You could do something along the lines of

```
import time
start_frame = time.time()
noi = 16
frames_per_second = 10
```

Then in your loop put

```
current_image = int((time.time() - start_frame) * frames_per_second % noi)
```

**time.time()** counts up in seconds and has several decimal places after it. If you leave leave out **frames_per_second** then just use the modulo operator on **noi** (presumably "number of images"), every time a second has gone by, the result will tick up one until it reaches 16 and return to 0.

When you multiply the difference between **start_frame** and current time (**time.time()**), you force the "seconds" to go by **frames_per_second** times as fast.

Coercing the result which will be a *float* to an *int*, will allow you to use it as an index.

Now if the frame rate of the game fluctuates, it won't matter because the frame rate of the sprite is tied to the system clock. The sprites should still run at as close to exactly the chosen frame rate as can be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

[`Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) is the correct solution.

While you may want to run the code of your game as fast as possible, you don't want the *animation* to run at an arbitrary speed. Animation is always "frames per second" and this value should be stable; otherwise it will look ugly or confusing. A good value is the same as the refresh rate of your monitor (usually 60 FPS) to avoid [tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).